# Submit button does not pass form data

Tags: html, forms

Here is my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/abc" method="POST">
   <div><input type="text" id="name" value="a"></div>
   <div class="border-top row">
      <button type="submit" class="btn float-right" name="update">Update 
      </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

When I click button it just pass data like below:

```
   update:
```

Why is it not showing other form data?

Comment: `<input type="text" id="name" value="a">` This needs a `name="someName"` property in order for you to access it server side. - Voting to close this as a simple typographical error

Comment: specify action page where you send request

Comment: Thanks, Was wondering why this form does not work, and other form works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add name attribute to the input field to get the value of text-box on click of submit button.

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" action="/abc" method="POST">
       <div><input type="text" id="name" value="a" name="uname"></div>
       <div class="border-top row">
          <button type="submit" class="btn float-right" name="update">Update 
          </button>
       </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please [do not answer Off Topic - Simple Typographical Error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions/133555#133555) questions.